# How to transfer files from linux(Fedora) to Windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, fedora, file-transfer, filezilla

I wanted to know how would I be able to transfer files from linux onto windows server 2003. Do I need to install a filezilla server on the windows and connect from my linux to windows and transfer the files or is there any other process that would help me in transferring files from linux to windows.

I am developing a website on the localhost and want to transfer the files from my local machine to remote windows server.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a pretty simple one for you to actually perform. Try using an SCP client like this: http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Should be straightforward once you get it installed.

Comment: I am sorry I am a newbie so finding it hard to find the requirements and installation instructions. I have installed winSCP on Windows server. I have not idea of how do I connect from the linux laptop to the server.

Comment: It's easiest if you connect to your Linux box from the Windows machine. Then it's just like a normal file browser (mostly), just move files over.